# Detecting when a fragment is on top again (has focus)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my app, my activity has a container with a fragment. When a button in that fragment is clicked, I add a new fragment to the container and add the previous fragment to the backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.primary_fragment_container, homeFragmentHandler);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(folderId.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The result is that pressing back closes the top fragment and returns me to the previous fragment, which is exactly how I want it. HOWEVER there are certain elements on the fragment that should be refreshed at this point. When the user clicks back and is returned to the previous fragment, how do I know to refresh the data within that fragment? is there a method such as onResume() for this scenario?

Comment: Fragments do have an onResume method. And it's quite suited for what you need.

Comment: @Ascorbin The onResume method wasn't called in this situation. It seems that the previous fragment never actually gets paused when the new fragment is added, so it never has to be resumed.

Comment: U can move from fragment to fragment by passing data as a bundle. Something similar to data being sent from activity to activity ia an intent. Everytime the original fragment is made, get the intent and check the data. If it was from the 2nd fragment then reload whatever data you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to proper add fragments to backstack:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment (); 

  transaction.replace(R.id.primary_fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: doing a replace instead of an add meant that my fragment was (probably) destroyed, which in my scenario is perfect and is the easiest solution since  all the logic for loading up the fragment happens now. Thanks!

Comment: @BooleanCheese but it doesn't answer your original question, now you have to rebuild the complete fragment

Answer (score 1):

```
    Fragment homeFragmentHandler= new Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //replace this line below wth something convinient
    bundle.putInt("key", value);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.primary_fragment_container, homeFragmentHandler);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(folderId.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This will send data regarding which fragment/ activity caused the previous fragment to load. Now in its onCreate add this code to check the data in the bundle

```
//In the onCreate of the original fragment
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if(bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue)!=null{
int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
// Load the data that needs to be refreshed when original fragment is loaded from the second one
}
```

No else statement is needed. If the fragment is made from any other activity/ fragment then the bundle.getInt will return null and hence that code inside the statement wont be executed.